# Unknown character on response of API Endpoint

Tags: php, api, unicode, drupal-7, response

My legacy project, which relies on Drupal 7 and PHP 5.6, is experiencing an issue where an unknown character is being added to certain data through the API endpoint. What's particularly perplexing is that this character is only appearing in some of the affected data, and I am uncertain as to what is causing it.

The presence of the unknown character is preventing us from properly decoding the API response, and although I have identified a workaround to remove the character prior to decoding, I have been tasked with investigating its origin. While I have been unable to reproduce the issue on my local environment, I require concrete evidence before making any changes to the production server.

Here is the hex of the unknown character (`efbb bf`):

[image]

Upon conducting a thorough search throughout my project, I have only been able to find the character in the [UnicodeTest.txt](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21tests%21UnicodeTest.txt/7.x) file, which is illustrated in the accompanying image.

[image]

ZWNBSP is the unknown character that shows in the beginning response of my API endpoint. If I copy and paste it's just like empty char. I can not send it on Google chat or other messaging apps. It seems I can not see that character on the browser, but I can see the character on PHPstorm terminal. You can check that char on [this page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21tests%21UnicodeTest.txt/7.x) before "！＂＃＄％＆ " characters

I don't know where it came from. Anybody has a clue?

The possibility that is on my mind:

1. Bug from CDN/WAF, we use CloudFlare
2. Bug from PHP on the production server
3. Bug from drupal 7.39 (not too sure since only fount that char in UnicodeTest.txt and only used in unit test)

Comment: `EF BB BF` is a BOM, Byte Order Mark.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, just realized the name. After I knew the name, found some similar issues like https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235000/byte-order-mark-appearing-at-the-beginning-of-api-calls, but still don't know the solution. Still finding.

Answer (score 0):

As [cbroe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75874744/unknown-character-on-response-of-api-endpoint#comment133834209_75874744) suggests, the byte sequence `EF BB BF` is the UTF-8 encoding of the character `U+FEFF`. That character is widely used as a Byte Order Mark at the start of text files.

However, a BOM character is not valid in `application/json` data (which from your screenshot your API response appears to be). An API that returns JSON data with a BOM is simply not compliant with the JSON spec. If the API's resource type were `text/plain` then a BOM would be acceptable.

I've had a similar problem in the past when integrating one piece of software which insisted on putting a BOM at the start of an XML resource (which *is* acceptable practice) with another piece of software which rejected any BOM, and in my case I fixed the problem with a work-around that stripped the BOM after it was created, and I later followed up by patching the second piece of software so it would accept a BOM.

It's hard to know where the `FEFF` character comes from, though I'd think it's unlikely to be your CDN; my guess would be Drupal or some PHP library responsible for serializing JSON. Good luck tracking it down!